# How to share a question on different related SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support, site-crossover, cross-posting

My question is that I asked a question on stackoverflow.com and 
I want to share my question to all other technical stackoverflow linked sites like http://dba.stackexchange.com, http://unix.stackexchange.com etc.

I want to share my question on only selected sites related to stackoverflow. I don't want to post duplicates, I just want to make my question visible for the users on the related site, that may not necessarily be the members of the both sites, but may be competent to answer.

Is there any option in StackExchange network to perform this operation?

Can any one suggest me how I can do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because some user has acccount on stackoverflow.com and other some has on dba.stackexchange.com and my question can see only same site account holders. If I spread my question on different sites then solving posibility of a question will be more and anyonce can get the fast response by spreading his/her question.

Comment: why -1, can you explain me. What I asked wrong?

Comment: Voting [is slightly different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), I voted down because the title suggests something (i.e. crossposting questions) I think is not a good idea. No offense intended.

Comment: PS. This may be related / relevant for you: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/162730)

Comment: People are downvoting because of your implied intent: *"If I spread my question on different sites then solving posibility of a question will be more"* -- the goal of SE is not to answer your question quickly, the goal is to get good questions that will collect good answers that will help people in the future. If you post a good question on the appropriate site you should have no trouble getting an answer. If you aren't getting an answer, the most likely reason is not because you didn't post it more places.

Comment: There are no 'related/linked cross-network questions'. If they were, you could post your link in comment to some related question on other site. As for now, the answer should be "No, but people are requesting it". The downvotes are probably based on the assumption, you ask if it's allowed to cross-post duplicates. I suggest looking on the second 'duplicate' link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option would be to post to all the sites manually but I would **strongly discourage** you to do so:

- You should post your question to the site that is more relevant. Posting it to another site just hoping to find someone interested makes no sense. Questions are organized by topic to attract the right audience
- Your question will most likely be moved to the correct site and then marked as a duplicate
- The majority of the users will be upset by seeing your question several times and vote it down.

Comment: Yes, I know the question may be off topic for other sites but not for all sites. So I am asking for share my question on selected relevent sites.

Comment: @GhostAnswer Do you have an example?

Comment: yes, If I have a database configuration issue on windows server then the issue may be due to operating system or may be database setup. now I asked my question on dba.stackexchange.com but not got apropriate result for my issue and now If I asked this question on other stackoverflow sites like server.stackexchange.com then it will be dupicates of my previous question. So I want to share my question on different stackoverflow related sites.

Comment: No, it's not the only option, even without cross-site facilities. You can post **similar** questions, but **with site-specific accents**. Everything is in the discussion under the 'duplicate' links.